# Search if div contains class (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, contains

I started with vanilla JS, so don't be mad ;)
Try to code tic tac toe game.

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cel empty" id="a1">
            <p>x</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cel empty" id="a2">
            x
        </div>
        <div class="cel empty" id="a3">
            x
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cel empty" id="b1"> x</div>
        <div class="cel empty" id="b2"> x</div>
        <div class="cel empty" id="b3"> x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cel empty" id="c1"> x</div>
        <div class="cel empty" id="c2"> x</div>
        <div class="cel empty" id="c3">x </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also this JS:

```
var fieldEmptyElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.cel');//pobieram divy które zawierają klasę empty

    window.addEventListener('load', checkHowManyEmpty);//po załadowaniu strony wczytuje funkcję o nazwie checkHowManyEmpty


    //funkcja ma za zadanie sprawdzić jak dużo pól div ma klasę empty
    function checkHowManyEmpty(){
        for(var i=0, max=fieldEmptyElements.length; i<max; i++){
            if(fieldEmptyElements.classList.contains('empty')){
                alert('there is one element with empty class');
            }
            else{
                alert('no element with empty class');
            }
        }
    }
```

Function need to check if any element have class EMPTY - but console gave me this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined
    at checkHowManyEmpty". Any idea why?

Comment: *fieldEmptyElements* is a NodeList, use `fieldEmptyElements[i].classList.contains(..)`.

Comment: Why perform that check yourself in a loop, and not let the selector engine do the work? That's what it's optimized for anyway. `document.querySelectorAll('div.cel.empty').length` will tell you  whether there were elements with the class `empty` among those `div.cell` elements in one clean and easy method call ...

Comment: @Cbroe - but when i wrote this function:
`function checkHowManyEmpty(){
        var fieldEmptyElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.cel.empty');

        if(fieldEmptyElements.length >= 1){
            console.log('at least one element');
        }
        else if(fieldEmptyElements.length = 0){
            console.log('no empty elements');
        }
    }`

It shows me if there is elements with class empty in console.log but not when theres no element with this class...

Comment: `else if(fieldEmptyElements.length = 0)` - that's an _assignment_; the _comparison_ operator is `==` ... but why would you need an else-if here anyway? If the length is not `>= 1`, then it's gotta be 0 ... it can't go into the negative.

Comment: @CBroe yeaaah! I saw that mistake for a few second before you have answered :D  Anyway it works when you use comparison! 
And I use it because I'm learning and this kind of notation is better to remember what is what ;) 
Thanks!

Comment: Ha, in the spirit of learning I feel kinda bad now that you accepted my answer - whereas the others at least take a crack at explaining what the issue with your original approach was :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why perform that check yourself in a loop, and not let the selector engine do the work? That's what it's optimized for after all ...

`document.querySelectorAll('div.cel.empty').length` will tell you whether there are elements with the class `empty` among those `div.cell` elements in one simple method call.

Your function example from the comments - unnecessary else-if replaced with a simple else:

```
function checkHowManyEmpty() {
    var fieldEmptyElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.cel.empty');
    if (fieldEmptyElements.length >= 1) {
        console.log('at least one element');
    } else {
        console.log('no empty elements');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually meant to do this: (You should access the current index of the collection)

```
// ...
if (fieldEmptyElements[i].classList.contains('empty')) {
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

fieldEmptyElements is an array. To access an item in an array you need the index which in your case is the i variable.
For every iteration of the loop i increases by 1.

```
if (fieldEmptyElements[i].classList.contains('empty'))
```

This way you access the item of the array with the current index.

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll() returns a node list. You are then looking at the classList property of the node list. This is wrong as you need to check each element in the node list and then check its classList.

In your for loop you would use your var i to index your node list.

fieldEmptyElements[i].classList